# Customer logged in condition not working on controller

Tags: magento2.4.1, magento-commerce

My controller,

```
     <?php
/**
 *
 * Copyright © 2015 Zmagecommerce. All rights reserved.
 */
namespace Zero\my_module\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory;


class Wishlist extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $_customerSession;
    protected $_resultJsonFactory;
    protected $wishlistProvider;
    protected $_wishlistRepository;
    protected $_productRepository;
    protected $customerSession;
    protected $urlInterface;
    protected $_session;
    protected $storeManager;
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $session,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlInterface,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        \Magento\Wishlist\Model\WishlistFactory $wishlistRepository,
        JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory,
        \Magento\Wishlist\Controller\WishlistProviderInterface $wishlistProvider,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
    ) {
        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->_wishlistRepository = $wishlistRepository;
        $this->_resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
        $this->wishlistProvider = $wishlistProvider;
        $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->urlInterface = $urlInterface;
        $this->_session = $session;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {  
        
        //Redirect to login page if customer is not logged in
        // if (!$this->customerSession->isLoggedIn()) 
        // {
           
        //     $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage("You must be logged in to add/update product");
        //     $this->customerSession->setAfterAuthUrl($this->urlInterface->getCurrentUrl());
        //     $this->customerSession->authenticate();
        //     return;
        // }
        if($this->_session->isLoggedIn()) {
        $response = [];
        $productId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('productId');
        $customerId = $this->_customerSession->getCustomer()->getId();
        // $customerId = $this->_customerSession->getCustomerId();

        if ($productId && $customerId) {
            try {
                $product = $this->_productRepository->getById($productId);
            } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
                $product = null;
            }

            if ($product) {
                $wishlist = $this->_wishlistRepository->create()->loadByCustomerId($customerId, true);
                $wishlist->addNewItem($product);
                $wishlist->save();
                $response['productid'] = $productId;
            }
        
        $resultJson = $this->_resultJsonFactory->create();
        $resultJson->setData($response);
        return $resultJson;
        }
        
        }else{
        $url = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl();
        $login_url = $this->urlInterface
                          ->getUrl('customer/account/login',
                                array('referer' => base64_encode($url))
                            );
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        $resultRedirect->setUrl($login_url);
        return $resultRedirect;
        }

    }
}
```

customer logged-in condition error?

Comment: can u try with this $this->customerSession->getCustomerId();

Comment: where i can add this https://codeshare.io/5gQ93V

Comment: use this if($this->customerSession->isLoggedIn()){ ....... }

Comment: can you pls explain with my code pls

Comment: if not logged in i need to redirect to login page

Comment: plz try with this logic it will work https://codeshare.io/2Bw7RK

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120154/discussion-between-zus-and-nagaraju-k).

Comment: @NagarajuK https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120154/discussion-between-zus-and-nagaraju-k can pls join the chat

Comment: i just updated my code, its not working.

Comment: @NagarajuK Can you pls help me to figure out the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Change your `$customerId = $this->_customerSession->getCustomer()->getId();` to this:

```
$customerId = $this->_customerSession->getCustomerId();
```

This should work.

OR you can also call `isLoggedIn()` function:

```
//\Magento\Customer\Model\Session
/**
 * Checking customer login status
 *
 * @api
 * @return bool
 */
public function isLoggedIn()
{
    return (bool)$this->getCustomerId()
        && $this->checkCustomerId($this->getId())
        && !$this->getIsCustomerEmulated();
}
```

If you want, you can also force to login:

Just add this funtion in your controller:

```
/* Check customer authentication
 *
 * @param RequestInterface $request
 * @return \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface
 */
public function dispatch(RequestInterface $request)
{
    if (!$this->_customerSession->authenticate()) {
        $this->_actionFlag->set('', 'no-dispatch', true);
    }
    return parent::dispatch($request);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Not working --> $customerId = $this->_customerSession->getCustomerId();

Comment: You have problem in your consturctor. Use this instead: `$this->_session->getCustomerId();`

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if customer is currently logged in, if not, then you need to redirect to login page with referral URL, so that customer with redirect back to you page after login

You can use this code to do this:

```
protected $customerSession;
protected $urlInterface;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
    \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlInterface,
    ...
)
{
    $this->urlInterface = $urlInterface;
    $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
    ...
}
```

Then in execute function, add this one at start of function

```
//Redirect to login page if customer is not logged in
if(!$this->customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
    $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage("You must be logged in to add/update product");
    $this->customerSession->setAfterAuthUrl($this->urlInterface->getCurrentUrl());
    $this->customerSession->authenticate();
    return;
}
```

Comment: I am updated your code with my code -> https://codeshare.io/amdAZ1 i am gettting 500 error, can you pls help me